# Delete Cascade Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql

I wonder whether someone can help me please.

I have the following three tables:

**Parent Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `userdetails` (
  `userid` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `forename` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `emailaddress` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `passwordhint` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `subscriptionexpiration` date NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`userid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `emailaddress` (`emailaddress`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**Child Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `detectinglocations` (
  `userid` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `locationid` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `locationname` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(110) NOT NULL,
  `osgb36lat` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `osgb36lon` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `osgridref` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `wgs84latd` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `wgs84latm` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `wgs84lats` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `wgs84latb` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `wgs84lond` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `wgs84lonm` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `wgs84lons` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `wgs84lonb` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `nameoflocationcontact` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `locationcontactsaddressline1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `locationcontactsaddressline2` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `locationcontactsaddressline3` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `locationcontactsaddressline4` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `locationcontactstelephonenumber` varchar(15) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`locationid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**Child Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `detectors` (
  `userid` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `detectorid` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `detectorname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`detectorid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PACK_KEYS=0 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Using the this code below, I'm trying to implement the 'Delete Cascade' functionality, whereby if the user is deleted from the parent table, the associated rows within the child tables are alse deleted.

```
ALTER TABLE 'tablename'
   add CONSTRAINT fk_userdetails
   FOREIGN KEY (userid)
   REFERENCES userdetails(userid)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I can successfully implement this for the first child table, but when I try to do the same with the second child table I receive the following error:

```
#1005 - Can't create table './db369054642/#sql-30d_bd1a57.frm' (errno: 121)
```

I've done quite a bit of research to find out what the problem may be, but I must admit I'm none the wiser.

Could someone perhaps have a look at this please and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html in the post by  Mark Robbins on September 29 2007 10:19pm and the next one:

- Constraint names must be unique
- fk_userdetails is not unique

So you might try

```
ALTER TABLE 'tablename'
   add CONSTRAINT fk_userdetails_detectors
   FOREIGN KEY (userid)
   REFERENCES userdetails(userid)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
```

on the second table

Comment: There's no need to specify a constraint name anyways. MySQL will create one automatically. So a simple `alter table X add foreign key ...` will work fine.

Comment: So it is, but a human-readable and -understandable name might be preferrable.

Comment: not really. The constraint name is only relevant if you're dropping or modifying it, and can be easily retrieved from a `show create table X` call.

Comment: As the OP explicitly gave a constraint name, I assumed to a human-readable and -understandable name to be preferrable to him. It also is for me, it might not be for you. In no case is it relevant to the problem, as long as it is unique - which can be achieved by giving none or by giving a unique one.

Comment: @Marc B and Eugen Rieck, many thanks for your help, I've now managed to successfully implement the 'Delete Cascade' functionality.